# Disable scrolling without scroll top zero by overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, css, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal and on showing that, the background should not be allowed to scroll. I could use `overflow: hidden` for the item list container. But it causes the page scroll to top and it should not be allowed. Any idea?

Comment: Could we have the code of what you have so far, please? Also, if I understand what you want correctly, have you tried using `background-attachment: fixed;`?

Comment: @sap what version of bootstrap you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
html { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Hope this helps!

Note that this will disable the scroll bar.